# Interrogating InDesign file beyond XMP Metadata

Tags: c++, adobe-indesign

So, I've got an app that needs to deal with files created by Adobe InDesign (.INDD), and while the XMP Metadata is useful, there are additional things that I want to know about the files that do not appear to be in the metadata.

Specifically, I would want to know the number of actual pages (not just number of page previews created), and what the dimensions of those pages are.

Has anyone run across any toolkit, sdk, etc. that can get me this information?

This will be for a non-open source commercial app, so licenses are a potential roadblock.  Also, this app will not be a plug-in for any Adobe product, so the InDesign Plugin SDK is not an option either.

C++ is the preferred language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.indd is a proprietary format owned by Adobe. You are not allowed to interact with this format outside of InDesign. If the documents are saved in the .idml format, it's quite possible and not very difficult, but if all you have to work with is a bunch of .indd files that someone else created, you're gonna have to use a plugin or scripts together with InDesign.

Comment: Thank you for the information and suggestion about .idml.  I will investigate it and possibly recommend adding support for that.